# .NET JWT Implementation accepting expired tokens

Tags: c#, jwt, access-token

I am generating a valid JWT in my API, and returning it with an expiry embedded. See code and example below:

```
    public static string GenerateToken(string securityKey,
        string claimName, string issuer, RedisManagerPool redisClient)
    {
        var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,
                claimName)
            };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(UtilityCommand.Cache.GetCacheValue<int>(Functions.ParameterPath 
            + Functions.Integration 
            + Functions.JWT 
            + "/expiry_minutes", redisClient));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: issuer,
            audience: issuer,
            claims: claims,
            expires: expiry,
            signingCredentials: creds);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Example:

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "scpi",
  "exp": 1598960076,
  "iss": "https://lcsapi",
  "aud": "https://lcsapi"
}
```

But no matter how long I use the token for, it never expires? Where am I going wrong here? Even if I set the expiry to something like 1 minute. Here is my auth check:

```
    public APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse GetAuthentication(APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest authorizerRequest, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = UtilityCommand.Cache.GetCacheValue<bool>(ParameterPath + Integration + JWT + "/jwtexpires", _redisClient), // testing
            ValidAudience = Issuer,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey)),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), // Required to account for potential drift times between systems. 
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        bool authorized = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorizerRequest.AuthorizationToken))
        {
            try
            {
                var jwt = authorizerRequest.AuthorizationToken.Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);
                var user = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
                var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                if (claim != null)
                    authorized = claim.Value == ClaimName; // Ensure that the claim value matches the assertion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Error occurred validating token: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Error occurred validating token: No token provided.");
        }

        return GenerateAuthorizerResponse(authorized, authorizerRequest, context);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you've resolved it. Worth making sure you are checking expiry against DateTime.UtcNow, since the expiry claim is a UTC value.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, I needed to add the following to my TokenValidationParameters.

```
LifetimeValidator = LifetimeValidator,
```

Which accepts a delegate function that checks the expiry (I didn't realise this wasn't handled automatically). It's just a bool return on whether the expiry is passed:

```
private bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken token, TokenValidationParameters @params)
{
    if (expires != null)
    {
        return expires > DateTime.Now;
    }
    return false;
}
```